# Terminal Errors in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, bashrc, konsole

I am getting a strange printout of what appears to be errors in my terminal when I load the app in Kubuntu 20.04. I first noticed it while using Hyper Terminal, but then I tried Konsole and got the same thing.

[image]

Comment: I notice you tagged your question `bashrc` - did you modify either `/etc/bash.bashrc` or your `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: As @steeldriver suggests, it's likely something odd in your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Can you share any modifications that were made to those files?

Comment: I have isolated the possible issue for the errors to my .bash_profile. In this file, I have the following in my .bash_profile:

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Comment: If I comment out everything but the last line, the problem is fixed, no more errors. But, I was learning about aliases and I set my aliases up in .bash_aliases and I also have Anaconda installed. I noticed that my aliases were not available and I was not automatically in my Anaconda virtual environment anymore. So I searched online and found a side that recommended adding these lines to my .bash_profile. When I did, I got the desired results. So when I comment them out, I am back to square one. I cannot even activate Anaconda manually by running conda activate.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like there is some script amounting to spamming the `sudo` command into the terminal on startup without proper usage.  In case you are not aware, there are [various scripts](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/) that automatically run when you start a terminal, so you should check these haven't been broken or corrupted.  If you did not edit these files before, then it could be something you recently installed that caused it.